# Serializing data when debugging in VS 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

is there some way (or some extension) to serialize object when debugging in Visual Studio (2010)?
we have really huge application based on asp.net and my IIS used to timed out, until I get the place, where problem is. What I need is to store some objects into json/xml/whatever and continue debugging so I can later check that objects values. It take too much time verifing every object in every iteration level in every method going through especially when the problem is at the very end.

Comment: There are a dozen and twenty ways to serialize objects, depending on the type of data; what have you tried?

Comment: I know how to serialize objects, if you try to think this way... my problem, is serialize it on demand when debugging... and calling some static serialize() method in Immediate window maybe can be a solution, even not too comfortable...

Comment: there's not going to be anything built-in for that, but sure you could write a static method to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Generally when I need some clarity of objects when debugging I override the ToString() method which changes what is displayed in the watch. ie

Instead of seeing "MyNamespace.someother.MyClass" in the watch, you may see something like "My custom ToString message!"

If you want to store the output, you would have to write your own function to do so (And then make sure it gets called when debugging... You could conditionally do this by checking System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached